# How to get index, position number of element with certain class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this markup

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

My question is: how to get "index" number of element with class `two`. I'm not asking of regular index number of element in `parent` div. I need to know that when i'm clicking at first element with class `one` that next `two` element have 0 index or it's first element in this list with class `two`, and so on.

I've tried with `index()` method and `eq()` and always i have the real index number of this element in `parent` div. I hope this is clear, thx for help.

Comment: It has to be in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the faster way to get the index you are looking for.

Instead of retrieving all matches, it just counts the number of elements of the same class among previous leafs in your DOM.

Also, it allows having multiple `<div class="parent">` and still work

```
$('.parent div').click(function() {
    // Retrieve clicked element class (one, two)
    var elClass = $(this).attr('class');

    // Retrieve all previous elements that have the same class
    // and count them
    var prevElmts = $(this).prevAll('.' + elClass),
        numPrevElements = prevElmts.length;

    console.log(numPrevElements);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the elements index in collection of element with sameclass:

```
$('.parent > div').click(function(){
 var index;
 if($(this).is('.one'))
    index = $('.parent > .one').index(this);
 else 
    index = $('.parent > .two').index(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using jquery you can find index of element which have same class name or tag name

```
$(".class_name").on("event_name", function() {
        var index=($(this).index());
        console.log('index : ',index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
var p = $('.parent'),
current = p.filter('.two'),
index = p.index(current);
```